# How can i use HTML 5 to acces database in my native application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, jquery-mobile

I have an iPad application, its basically a client - server application, HTML pages are loaded from the server. what I really want achieve is access my native applications database in this HTML page.

For example, the HTML page shows a table, in which its content are the values stored in the data base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard of [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service)?

You gonna have to utilise the web service and get data from server (server will talk to db server and get relevant data for you). Service usually returns data in XML or JSON format.

So you gonna have to learn how to write web services. You can write web services using most of the languages such as C#, PHP, Java. But choice is yours as per your requirement and available infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks for your response. :)
but what i actually want is to access my native application database using HTML 5, is there methods for that.??